# How to properly break CSS3 columns? A pixel line is in the wrong column

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

Currently building my WordPress Plugin, I am going over the styling and layout of it.

I have a  with  within. The div is css-set with columns: 2, and the children have column-break:avoid; (i tried all combinations) but it does still show a line from one , in the wrong column.

Image of what's wrong: [image]

The blue block leaves a one-pixel hight line on the left column, it should not.

```
<div class="parents columns two">

    <aside class="myp myp-card female">

        <a href="http://localhost/dev/#" title="Mother">

            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Skye_Medium.jpg" alt="View Mother" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="card-overlay">
                <h1 class="card-title">Mother</h1>
            </div>

        </a>

    </aside>

    <aside class="myp myp-card male">

        <a href="http://localhost/dev/#" title="Father">

            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Border_Collie_liver_portrait.jpg" alt="View Father" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="card-overlay">
                <h1 class="card-title">Father</h1>
            </div>

        </a>

    </aside>

</div>
```

And my CSS...

```
.columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;

  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
.columns > * { display: block; width: 100%;
  -webkit-column-break:avoid; -moz-column-break:avoid; -o-column-break:avoid; -ms-column-break:avoid; column-break:avoid; }

.columns.one { -webkit-column-count: 1; -moz-column-count: 1; column-count: 1; }
.columns.two { -webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; column-count: 2; }
.columns.three { -webkit-column-count: 3; -moz-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; }
.columns.four { -webkit-column-count: 4; -moz-column-count: 4; column-count: 4; }
.columns.five { -webkit-column-count: 5; -moz-column-count: 5; column-count: 5; }

.myp-card { position: relative; margin: 0 0 1em; padding: 0; }
.myp-card a { border:0; }
.myp-card .card-image { position: relative; background-color: #000; }
.myp-card .card-image img { opacity: .25; width: 100%; }
.myp-card .card-overlay { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
.myp-card .card-overlay .card-title { font-size: 1.1em; margin: 0; padding: 1em; color: #000; }
.myp-card a:hover .card-image img { opacity: 1; }
.myp-card a:hover .card-overlay { display: none; }

.myp-card.male .card-image {
    background: rgb(30, 115, 190);
}
.myp-card.male .card-overlay .card-title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.pedigree-tree li.male > span {
    border-color: rgb(30, 115, 190);
}
.male-color {
    color: rgb(30, 115, 190);
}
.myp-card.female .card-image {
    background: rgb(232, 37, 215);
}
.myp-card.female .card-overlay .card-title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.female-color {
    color: rgb(232, 37, 215);
}
```

How can I get rid of this line? I managed to do it with display: list-item; for the aside tags BUT it then creates a margin I cannot control (margin:0 and padding:0 do not work).

Thanks guys...

Comment: can you share some more of the HTML and CSS? I guess up until the mating part should do fine. Also the relevant CSS.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma the rest of the css is for the rest of the page. the mating part is after the closing </div>.. so this is the relevant html and css, i am crazily lost especially that I have used columns on many projects, but here, it messes things up :/

Comment: Are you talking about the blue line? I can't replicate that line in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/geqox13e/ That's why I asked about the rest of the code. I thought maybe the line i actually part of another element.

Comment: It works on Safari, firefox, but not on Chrome. I'll keep on searching, weird as hell..

Comment: Can't see the problem in Firefox either when I open the fiddle. Are you seeing the line in the Fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/geqox13e/

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, somewhere in your css you used `vertical-align: bottom;` for the images? Deactivating this was for me the solution, because I recently had the same problem...

Comment: Do you see `vertical-align: bottom;` anywhere in the OP's code?